# passing data from one Window to another

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 windows. When I press a button, I want to pass a `Person` object from current `Window` to the other one.

This is the code in the main window:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    person owner = new person();
    owner.ID = 1;
    owner.Name = "Mark";
    w2 newWindow = new w2(owner);

    newWindow.Show();
}
```

In the other window named `w2` I have this code:

```
public partial class w2 : Window
{
    public class person
    {
        int _ID;
        string _Name;

        public int ID
        {
            get { return _ID; }
            set { _ID = value; }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; }
        }
   }

   public w2()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   public w2(person passedPerson) : this()
   { 
       this.passedPerson = passedPerson;
   }
}
```

I get these errors when I try to compile:

> Error 3   'passing.w2' does not contain a definition for 'passedPerson' and no extension method 'passedPerson' accepting a first argument of type 'passing.w2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?    48  18  passing
>
> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'passing.w2.w2(passing.w2.person)' has some invalid arguments  57  28  passing
>
> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'passing.MainWindow.person' to 'passing.w2.person'      57  35  passing

BTW. I've using this example as a starting point:

http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/pass-variables-windowopen-wpf-31068.aspx

Comment: OMG.. please don't use WPF in a winforms way... that's the worst thing you can do

Comment: im kinda new to c# alltogether so right now most of what i code is half sacrilege :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, the easy one:

> 'passing.w2' does not contain a definition for 'passedPerson'

When you say:

```
this.passedPerson = passedPerson;
```

Clearly you're trying to assign an instance field for the person, but there is no such field.  Just add one:

```
private person passedPerson;
```

For the other two errors, it's a result of the fact that you have defined two `person` classes, one in each window.  You shouldn't be doing that.  Just because there are two classes that have the same name and the same fields, doesn't make them the same class, and doesn't mean that you can treat one as if it were the other.

Create your `person` class at the top level (meaning in it's own file, ideally), and ensure that both windows use that one definition.

Also note that, by convention, class names start with an upper case letter:

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly assign each property of the passed person. what I mean is try to do

```
public w2(MainForm.person passedPerson)
        : this()
{
    this.passedPerson.ID = passedPerson.ID;
    this.passedPerson.Name = passedPerson.Name;
}
```

You might have defined 2 classes for Person. One in each form.

Although you should only define person one time only. (Create a seperate class and use it for both forms)

Comment: in your MainWindow did you define another public class person ?

Comment: tried to pass just a string and it works like i thought it should... but i still cant pass the entire class

Comment: Even with the same definition you cannot directly assign them. When you tried my proposed solution what error you got?

Comment: Try to use `public w2(MainForm.person passedPerson)` in my proposed solution

Comment: Error 1 'passing.w2' does not contain a definition for 'passedPerson' and no extension method 'passedPerson' accepting a first argument of type 'passing.w2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  50 18 passing
Error 2 'passing.w2' does not contain a definition for 'passedPerson' and no extension method 'passedPerson' accepting a first argument of type 'passing.w2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  51 18 passing

Comment: tried it, dosent work... 
i solved it by passing each variable separately to the second window... it's not the most elegant solution but it works =)

Answer (score 1):

try this,first window LoginPageWindow

```
public partial class LoginPageWindow : Window
 {

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       new Suucessfullogin(textboxvalue.text).ShowDialog();
    }
 }
```

in second window we can get value

```
public partial class Suucessfullogin : Window
{
      string str;   
    public Suucessfullogin(string value)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        str= value;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just nesting a class inside a class doesn't create a member of it.
Try

```
public partial class w2 : Window
{
   private person passedPerson;
   ....
}
```

Then populate your member with a reference.

Or better: put your class person outside of the other classes so they both have access to its definition.

Comment: +1 to neutralize: Maybe someone did not read carefullly enough, or thought you should add more cowbell.. For me, moving the persom out of the W2 and adding the prop/field is quite the correct answer (although moving is not strictly necessary:P)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your "owner" variable is of type person defined in w2 class (w2.person)? And where is your this.passedPerson field defined? It looks like it is not defined at all.
You should not create inner class if you want to use it outside the "parent" class. Just make Person class in a separate file.